# "Computing additional info" scala in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

when i write the name of an object and then a point and press control+space for showing methods, it opens a wondow with that error. The complete info of the error is:
An internal error occurred during: "Computing additional info".
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/JavaProject;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/WorkingCopyOwner;)V

I'm using Scala IDE 4.7.x download from the eclipse marketplace with the default settings.

I tried cleaning the project but the error keeps happening.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question as I have tried this on both MacOS and Ubuntu and have the same issue on both environments.

Until this is fixed, a work around is to ignore the error dialog box and to not close it. You can still use autocomplete despite the inconvenience.